# JQuery larger image in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-mobile

I have a thumbnail image declared dynamically like this :

```
<img id="productThumbnail" src="" style="float: left; width:100%"/>
```

I want to open a larger image in a JQuery dialog when a user clicks the thumbnail.
How can I accomplish this ?

Considering in my array, the thumbnail is "productThumbnail" and the larger image is "srcImg"
Something like :

```
<a href="#" data-rel="dialog" id="dialog1">
                    <img id="productThumbnail" src="" style="float: left; width:100%"/>
                </a>
```

Thanks !!

Comment: What jQuery plugin are you using for the dialogs? You should be able to use <a href=""> to link to the large image and load it that way.

Comment: Yes but I dont want to link directly to the image url. Like the thumbnail, I give it an id, I'd like to give an Id to the larger image which is srcImg.

Comment: And I'm not using any plugins... just this : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-dialogs.html

Comment: Okay so currently you have a thumbnail, and when they click on it you want to load a dialog window with the larger image?

Comment: Exactly. But I do not want it to be static. Something like href="image url" would not work for what I'm working on.

Comment: May I ask why? If you specify the <a href=""> and use http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ to prevent the link from functioning and doing the dialog window instead and if they have a non javascript browser they can see get to the link.

Comment: @JFFF let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1512/discussion-between-steven-and-jfff)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Appreciate it ! But I figured it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost exactly what jquery lightbox can do for you...is there a reason you can't or don't want to use it or other smiliar plugin?

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some of [this Jquery Pluggins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/) can help you.
(See the number 4).